# Rails add to model on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activemodel

I have a model Agent that `belongs_to` Scenario. Both models have the field `options` and I would like to merge the values stored in `Scenario` `options` with `Agent` `options` so that I can do `@agent.options` and retrieve the values from both `Agent` and `Scenario`.

I tried:

```
# in agent.rb
def options
  scenario.options.merge(self.options)
end
```

But this throws a `Stack too deep` error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brennan already explained that your `options` methods resursively calls itself what leads to the `Stack to deep` error.

There is an other (more low level) way to read an attribute of an active record model: `read_attribute`. Using that method you can write:

```
def options
  read_attribute(:options).merge(scenario.options)
end
```

This method exist exactly for this usecase. Read more about [overwriting default accessors in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Overwriting+default+accessors).

Answer (score 2):

Because `Agent` has a field *and* method named `options`, when calling `self.options` from within the class you call the method instead of retrieving the field. When you try to merge with `self.options`, you are recursing infinitely. Rename the method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had named the method the same as the field with the hope that I could override the call to `@agent.options` so that I can keep existing references to `@agent.options`. Is there a good way to merge the two options hashes on the fly so I can still call `options` but get both? I'm thinking the best way may be to merge the two in an `after_initialize` callback.